# Send gerrit metrics to graphite

Tags: gerrit, graphite

I have gerrit and graphite in my centos 7 vm. I have installed metrics-reporter-graphite plugin in gerrit. 
This is my metrics-reporter-graphite.config file

```
[graphite]
   host = http://127.0.0.1               ## Local host name##
   port = 2003
   prefix = gerrit
```

but metrics are not coming in graphite.  This is my log file

```
[2017-09-13 05:27:08,720] [metrics-graphite-reporter-1-thread-1] WARN  com.codahale.metrics.graphite.GraphiteReporter : Unable to report to Graphite
java.net.UnknownHostException: http://127.0.0.1
       at com.codahale.metrics.graphite.Graphite.connect(Graphite.java:122)
       at com.codahale.metrics.graphite.GraphiteReporter.report(GraphiteReporter.java:240)
       at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter.report(ScheduledReporter.java:251)
       at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter$1.run(ScheduledReporter.java:174)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

The plugin tries to resolve the given host name and fails:

> ```
> java.net.UnknownHostException: http://127.0.0.1
> ```

The reason for this is that a host name does not include the protocol and I doubt that graphite actually receives data via HTTP on port 2003. So the solution would be to update the configuration as follows:

```
[graphite]
   host = 127.0.0.1
   // ...
```